# Text in table is vertically centered

Tags: html, css

I have this table:

```
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td>Message</td>
        <td>Preview:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">
            <div style="float:left;">
                <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50" onkeyup="preview(this.value)">Enter your message here</textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:rgb(255, 170, 0);" id="preview">
            <div>Enter your message here</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's a textarea with a preview of how it will look next to it.
However, all the text in the preview cell is vertically centered, when I want it to start at the top.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td style="background-color:rgb(255, 170, 0); vertical-align: top;" id="preview"><div>Enter your message here</div></td>
```

Just add `vertical-align: top` property and then it should works.

Comment: Thanks! In 5 minutes stack overflow will let me accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `vertical-align:top` (by default it's work for table not other html element) 
read this:
http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

Answer (score 0):

add following code in css,

```
table tr td {
vertical-align:top;
}
```